# Spring boot pub/sub subcriber gets removed immediately after deployment

Tags: spring, google-cloud-platform, deployment, environment, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a spring boot app deployed to google cloud (via automatic github build).
Unfortunately my subscriber to pub/sub is being removed immediately after deployment :( Does anyone know reason for that?

```
Removing {service-activator:investobotAPIs.messageReceiver.serviceActivator} as a subscriber to the 'inputMessageChannel' channel
```

I've created a topic in google pub/sub and a subscription:
[image]

I've added these methods:

```
@RestController
@EnableAsync
public class InvestobotAPIs {

...
    
// [START pubsub_spring_inbound_channel_adapter]
        // Create a message channel for messages arriving from the subscription `sub-one`.
        @Bean
        public MessageChannel inputMessageChannel() {
            return new PublishSubscribeChannel();
        }
    
    // Create an inbound channel adapter to listen to the subscription `sub-one` and send
    // messages to the input message channel.
    @Bean
    public PubSubInboundChannelAdapter inboundChannelAdapter(
            @Qualifier("inputMessageChannel") MessageChannel messageChannel,
            PubSubTemplate pubSubTemplate) {
        PubSubInboundChannelAdapter adapter =
                new PubSubInboundChannelAdapter(pubSubTemplate, "fetch-gpw-sub");
        adapter.setOutputChannel(messageChannel);
        adapter.setAckMode(AckMode.MANUAL);
        adapter.setPayloadType(String.class);
        return adapter;
    }

    // Define what happens to the messages arriving in the message channel.
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "inputMessageChannel")
    public void messageReceiver(
            String payload,
            @Header(GcpPubSubHeaders.ORIGINAL_MESSAGE) BasicAcknowledgeablePubsubMessage message) {
        logger.info("Message arrived via an inbound channel adapter from fetch-gpw! Payload: " + payload);
        message.ack();
    }
    // [END pubsub_spring_inbound_channel_adapter]
```

and this is my build.graddle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.5.5'
    // get url and download files
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.6'
    implementation 'org.asynchttpclient:async-http-client:2.12.3'
    // parse xls files
    implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi:5.0.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:5.0.0'
    // firebase messaging and db
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:8.1.0'
    // subscribe pub/sub topic
    implementation 'com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub-stream-binder:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies:2.0.4'
}
```

Unfortunately when it is deployed the logs show that just after deployment is gets removed:

```
2021-10-20 11:51:16.190 CEST2021-10-20 09:51:16.190 INFO 1 --- [ main] o.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel : Channel 'application.inputMessageChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
Default
2021-10-20 11:51:16.190 CEST2021-10-20 09:51:16.190 INFO 1 --- [ main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer : started bean 'investobotAPIs.messageReceiver.serviceActivator'
Default
2021-10-20 11:51:16.214 CEST2021-10-20 09:51:16.214 INFO 1 --- [ main] .g.c.s.p.i.i.PubSubInboundChannelAdapter : started bean 'inboundChannelAdapter'; defined in: 'class path resource [com/miloszdobrowolski/investobotbackend/InvestobotAPIs.class]'; from source: 'com.miloszdobrowolski.investobotbackend.InvestobotAPIs.inboundChannelAdapter(org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel,com.google.cloud.spring.pubsub.core.PubSubTemplate)'
Default
2021-10-20 11:51:16.295 CEST2021-10-20 09:51:16.294 INFO 1 --- [ main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
Default
2021-10-20 11:51:19.076 CEST2021-10-20 09:51:19.075 INFO 1 --- [ main] c.m.i.InvestobotBackendApplication : Started InvestobotBackendApplication in 14.475 seconds (JVM running for 19.248)
Info
2021-10-20 11:51:22.386 CESTCloud Runinvestobot-backend-autobuild {@type: type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog, resourceName: namespaces/our-shield-329019/services/investobot-backend-autobuild, response: {…}, serviceName: run.googleapis.com, status: {…}}
Debug
2021-10-20 11:51:54.075 CESTContainer Sandbox: Unsupported syscall setsockopt(0x16,0x29,0x31,0x3e96fd1f3a9c,0x4,0x0). It is very likely that you can safely ignore this message and that this is not the cause of any error you might be troubleshooting. Please, refer to https://gvisor.dev/c/linux/amd64/setsockopt for more information.
Debug
2021-10-20 11:51:54.075 CESTContainer Sandbox: Unsupported syscall setsockopt(0x16,0x29,0x12,0x3e96fd1f3a9c,0x4,0x0). It is very likely that you can safely ignore this message and that this is not the cause of any error you might be troubleshooting. Please, refer to https://gvisor.dev/c/linux/amd64/setsockopt for more information.
Default
2021-10-20 11:52:59.196 CEST2021-10-20 09:52:59.195 WARN 1 --- [ault-executor-0] i.g.n.s.i.n.u.internal.MacAddressUtil : Failed to find a usable hardware address from the network interfaces; using random bytes: d1:79:21:a2:71:29:47:49
Default
2021-10-20 11:53:01.010 CEST2021-10-20 09:53:01.010 INFO 1 --- [ionShutdownHook] .g.c.s.p.i.i.PubSubInboundChannelAdapter : stopped bean 'inboundChannelAdapter'; defined in: 'class path resource [com/miloszdobrowolski/investobotbackend/InvestobotAPIs.class]'; from source: 'com.miloszdobrowolski.investobotbackend.InvestobotAPIs.inboundChannelAdapter(org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel,com.google.cloud.spring.pubsub.core.PubSubTemplate)'
Default
2021-10-20 11:53:01.010 CEST2021-10-20 09:53:01.010 INFO 1 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer : Removing {logging-channel-adapter:_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger} as a subscriber to the 'errorChannel' channel
Default
2021-10-20 11:53:01.010 CEST2021-10-20 09:53:01.010 INFO 1 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel : Channel 'application.errorChannel' has 0 subscriber(s).
Default
2021-10-20 11:53:01.011 CEST2021-10-20 09:53:01.011 INFO 1 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer : stopped bean '_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger'
Default
2021-10-20 11:53:01.011 CEST2021-10-20 09:53:01.011 INFO 1 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer : Removing {service-activator:investobotAPIs.messageReceiver.serviceActivator} as a subscriber to the 'inputMessageChannel' channel
Default
2021-10-20 11:53:01.011 CEST2021-10-20 09:53:01.011 INFO 1 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel : Channel 'application.inputMessageChannel' has 0 subscriber(s).
Default
2021-10-20 11:53:01.011 CEST2021-10-20 09:53:01.011 INFO 1 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer : stopped bean 'investobotAPIs.messageReceiver.serviceActivator'
```

I've tried to change dependencies in gradle from com.google.cloud to org.springframework.cloud (not sure how they differ)

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.5.5'
    // get url and download files
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.6'
    implementation 'org.asynchttpclient:async-http-client:2.12.3'
    // parse xls files
    implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi:5.0.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:5.0.0'
    // firebase messaging and db
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:8.1.0'
    // subscribe pub/sub topic
//  implementation 'com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub:2.0.4'
//  implementation 'com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub-stream-binder:2.0.4'
//  implementation 'com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies:2.0.4'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-bus-pubsub:1.2.8.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub:1.2.8.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-autoconfigure:1.2.8.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:5.5.4'
}
```

But it only causes a different error during deployment:
ERROR: (gcloud.run.services.update) Cloud Run error: Container failed to start. Failed to start and then listen on the port defined by the PORT environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information.

Comment: Hi @Milosz, could you please provide the steps for me able to have a [minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: I have tested a similar [example](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-gcp-pubsub/#initial) provided by the [spring.io](https://spring.io/) just cloning the project into the `Cloud Shell` and running. In my enviroment, the  application just remove he subscription when the program is being interrupted, So it's not being caused by PubSub. As your application fails to start, the regular procedure is remove the subscription before interrupt the application.

Comment: Please, try to add the following dependencies, as recommended by the spring tutorial.   `dependencies {
    ...
    compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub:1.2.5.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core")
    ...
}`

Here is the link for the full [build.gradle](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-messaging-gcp-pubsub/blob/main/complete/build.gradle) file.

Comment: Hi @ewertonvsilva - as I have explained in the post - I have already tried that -> using org.springframework.cloud causes different error - it doesn;t even build dure to the: " ERROR: (gcloud.run.services.update) Cloud Run error: Container failed to start. Failed to start and then listen on the port defined by the PORT environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information."

Comment: Ok, I've added server.port = 8080 in application properties, which removed the port error - but it only brought me to square one - so now even with "org.springframework.cloud" libraries I'm getting 
> 2021-10-20 11:53:01.011 CEST2021-10-20 09:53:01.011 INFO 1 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer : Removing {service-activator:investobotAPIs.messageReceiver.serviceActivator} as a subscriber to the 'inputMessageChannel' channel

Comment: The `removing subscriber` is a **intended behavior** Your code is failing is some other step and as result, before the termination spring is removing the subscription, this is expected.

Comment: But there is NO error message AND it works locally...